# Android CalendarView: How do I get the date in correct format?

Tags: android, date-format, calendarview

The past few days I've been searching for ways to get a 'readable' date out of my calendarview from android 4.0. I can't manage to find a solution or example that suits my problem. I did get it in miliseconds but not in a date format.

My problem is: I have a calendarview and I want the selected date by the user, shown in logcat in a dateformat yy-mm-dd.

I was used to the datepicker from android 2.2 and I'm not familiar with calendarview and can't find much about it either. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

Okay so here is how to do this. When you fire your calendarview activity or a calendarview inside your activity it sets the date to the current date(meaning today). To get this current date just use the `Calendar` object provided by the java api to get this date example below:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
// for your date format use
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
// set a string to format your current date
String curDate = sdf.format(date.getTime());
// print the date in your log cat
Log.d("CUR_DATE", curDate);
```

to get a date changed you must do this

```
CalendarView myCalendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.myCalenderid);

myCalendar.setOnDateChangeListener(myCalendarListener);

OnDateChangeListener myCalendarListener = new OnDateChangeListener(){

public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day){

   // add one because month starts at 0
   month = month + 1;
   // output to log cat **not sure how to format year to two places here**
   String newDate = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
   Log.d("NEW_DATE", newDate);
}
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the solution to convert the millisecond date to a normal readable format, and this did the trick!

Comment: @KalaJ it is an OnDateChangeListener. See the api reference:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener.html

Answer (score 3):

kandroidj's answer helps to create date, but not date of correct format.
So to format selected date:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                    int dayOfMonth) {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        String sDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        Log.d(TAG, "sDate formatted: " + sDate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String selectedDate = sdf.format(new Date(calendar.getDate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long date = calenderView.getDate();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(date);
int Year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int Month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int Day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//customize According to Your requirement
String finalDate=Year+"/"+Month+"/"+Day;
```

Comment: This doesn't fit the question because `CalendarView.getDate()` returns the current date (or a min date if it's later than the current date), not the selected date. Only solutions with `setOnDateChangeListener` fit here.